# Doctrine- Group by date

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this query :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(exp_date, "%Y-%m") AS Month, sum(exp_total) FROM export
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(exp_date, "%Y-%m");
```

I tried to convert it to Symfony doctrine like below :

```
$qb = $this
  ->createQueryBuilder('e')
  ->select('DATE_FORMAT(e.expDate, \'%Y-%m\'), sum(e.expTotal) total')
  ->groupBy('DATE_FORMAT(e.expDate, \'%Y-%m\')');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Using:

```
"beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0"
```

> Error: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 103 near
>   'DATE_FORMAT(e.expDate,': Error: Cannot group by undefined
>   identification or result variable.

Comment: what is the type of your expDate, is it Date or DateTime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you have configured the mentioned bundle and added the required [configuration](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/config/mysql.yml) like

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                date_format: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\DateFormat
```

Now in query you can assign an alias as `dateAsMonth` to the result of `DATE_FORMAT` expression and in group by you can use this alias

```
return $qb =   $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->select('DATE_FORMAT(e.expDate, \'%Y-%m\') as dateAsMonth, sum(e.expTotal) total')
                    ->groupBy('dateAsMonth')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
```

Comment: Unrecognized option "dql" under "doctrine.orm" in doctrine/orm 2.5.

Comment: @felansu you probably forgot to set up doctrine extensions as described in the link he provided (configuration)